# iPhone Xcode UIButton Title Will Not Appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, title

So I am making an iPhone program and for some odd reason the title of my UIButtons will not show... am I missing something??

I get no errors or even warnings on compilation and my buttons and everything appear, just the title is not being shown....

```
FurballViewController.m

...

-(void)loadView {

  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 40)];
  [btn setTitle:@"Stupid Title Wont Work" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:btn];
  [btn release];

}

...
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but you shouldn't be releasing the button after adding it as a subview—in general, you're only responsible for releasing things you've called "alloc", "copy", or "retain" on. As-is, the button's getting released while it's still in the hierarchy, which may cause some weird problems and potential crashes.

Comment: Your ...s are in the wrong place (self.view is not initialized!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out guys. I released the btn. I suppose when an object is initialized without alloc you dont release it. This code works:

```
FurballViewController.m

...

-(void)loadView {

  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 40)];
  [btn setTitle:@"Stupid Title Wont Work" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:btn];
  //[btn release];

}

...
```

Comment: sure... you used (+) class method.. which has autorelease method. you don't need to release it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the title text color? It could be white.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. UIButtonTypeRoundedRect sets a default dark-bluish color.